# Checking the value of a dropdowns in sql php

Tags: php, css, sql-server, pdo, drop-down-menu

I have two tables in SQL Server database. One table called matrix has all the values to display in a web table and the other table matrix-dropdowns have the values of the cells that have dropdowns. I want to have different background colors for the cell values of dropdowns in the web table, say if q1, then green color, if q2, yellow color. I could not figure out where to create a function to compare the cell values and return background color accordingly. The code snippet is shown below:

```
<?php
require_once('include/database.php');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<section>
    <table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Capacity</th>
     <th>Ownership</th>
     <th>Action</th>
     </tr>
     </thead> 

       <tbody>
        <?php
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM MATRIX ORDER BY OBJECTID ASC");
        $stmt ->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row) {
         ?>

          <tr>
          <td><?=$row['Ownership'];?></td>
          <td><?=$row['Capacity'];?></td>
          <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?=$row['OBJECTID'];?>">Edit </a>  </td>

           </tr>
           </tbody>

        <?php
         }
         ?>
```

Comment: First you need another mysql qiery.

Comment: Thanks u_mulder. Can I create another sql query next to the previous one?